# Xcode 8 - Localize string issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

I'm trying to localize some of my hard-coded strings. I inserted string manually  in Main.strings (Arabic) file like this:

```
"nav-title-hey" = "مرحبا";
```

And I coded in viewDidLoad().

```
self.navigationController.title = NSLocalizedString(@"nav-title-hey", @"Navigation Title: Hey");
```

And I ran my project, but string "nav-title-hey" was displayed on Navigation bar.

Who can teach me about issue?

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to make sure of:
**1) You are copying your strings file into your main bundle resources, in your xcproj settings:**
[image]

**2) Your strings file has Arabic checked in the File Inspector, like I have German checked here:**

[image]

**3) You have Arabic set as your OS Language, in the "Language and Region" preferences.  It needs to be the top-most language.  The OS will prompt you to restart, but I personally have never needed to, just re-build your application and it should stick**

[image]